# Optional type 'Bool' cannot be used as a boolean; test for '!= nil' instead

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, boolean, option-type

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject?) {
          if (segue && segue!.identifier == "showDetail"){  //this line has error
            var selectedIndexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
            var detailViewController : DetailViewController = segue!.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
            detailViewController.toDoData = toDoItems.objectAtIndex(selectedIndexPath.row) as NSDictionary
        }
```

I am very newby, it may be very simple error, but I need well explained answer.
I have Xcode error

> Optional type 'Bool' cannot be used as a boolean; test for '!= nil'
>   instead

for the second line `segue && segue!.identifier`.

I am watching youtube video to follow steps for the to-do list.

Comment: write condition as if(**segue != nil** && segue!.identifier == "showDetail")

Comment: Easier: segue?.identifier == "showDetail"

Answer (score 0):

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject?) {
      if (segue != nil && segue!.identifier == "showDetail"){  //this line has error
        var selectedIndexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        var detailViewController : DetailViewController = segue!.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
        detailViewController.toDoData = toDoItems.objectAtIndex(selectedIndexPath.row) as NSDictionary
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Read the message carefully.

You have an optional value, and you are using it as a Bool value. The message tells you that you cannot do this. Take a book about Swift and read up how to check whether an optional is nil or not. (Hint: Many things that are bad practice in C or C++ are illegal in Swift).